# JavaScript: read and write json file

Tags: javascript, json, pact

I have generated json file from my consumer pact in javaScript. When it's generating json file it doesn't contain what I expect. So, now I want to add block to my json file which I don't know how to do? Can someone here help me with that? so, basically I want to read json then create block and then write into json and save data

```
"path": {
  "dataType": "String",
  "expression": "data/xml/${id}",
  "key": "request"
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: Read the JSON from the file and parse it to an object. Add the desired property to the object. Stringify the object and write it back to the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "block"?

Comment: @CptPiepmatz, I mentioned in question for path the property

Comment: This question is currently very hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Please provide your test code, the code under test, what you are trying to do, what is happening and what you expect to happen. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You might also benefit from the tutorials/examples here https://docs.pactflow.io/docs/examples/

Answer (score 0):

As @Barmar pointed out you can simply parse your JSON text and modify it.

```
let yourJsonText = "{...}"; // read in your json however you want
let yourJson = JSON.parse(yourJsonText);

// then modify your object
yourJson.path.newAttr = "something you like";

// parse it back to a JSON string
let yourUpdatedJsonText = JSON.stringify(yourJson);
```